# Google Sheets Script: How to run function on loop over all sheets in workbook and onOpen?

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want a script to highlight a cell if another cell is yesterday's date (then remove the previous highlights). I want the script to run whenever I open the spreadsheet and when I switch to another tab.

I originally just had the script run as a `.setActiveSelection()` or a `.getRange("B:B").activate()`, but it's easier to notice when the cell is highlighted. But then I have to remove the previous highlights.

I'm trying to get my function to work over all my sheets to highlight a cell (col  E) in the same row if the date=today()-1 (col B) and remove the highlight in column E if the date (col B) < today()-1. Right now, I'm using a script to set the highlight and conditional formatting to remove any previous highlights. However, the script only runs on the active sheet, and either has to use the trigger `onOpen` or I have to set it to run every minute.

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39170376/google-sheets-script-apply-to-specific-tabs-within-a-sheet) saying I could use this in my code to run a loop through all my sheets (the first 6 tabs):

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheets[i]);
}
```

However, when I add it, I get an error message saying:

> Cannot call method "getRange" of null

Should I just use conditional formatting to highlight a specific date and remove previous highlighting?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oUPWWA8NbT6pYve3pFvBlKm7PNCj3XxnM020yp-rRHs/edit?usp=sharing

My full function:

```
function jumpToAmtEaten() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheets[i]);
    var r = sheet.getRange("B:B");
    var values = r.getValues();  
    var day = 24*3600*1000;  
    var today = parseInt((new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))/day);  
    var ssdate; 
    for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
      try {
        ssdate = values[i][0].getTime()/day;
      }
      catch(e) {
      }
      if (ssdate && Math.floor(ssdate) == today-1) {
        sheet.setActiveRange(r.offset(i,3,1,1)).setBackground("yellow"); 
        break;                               
      }                                       
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheets[i]);
```

You're passing a a Sheet object to the method `getSheetByName()` instead of a name. Also you don't need to keep calling a `getSheet` method once you've already obtained them once. Try this instead:

```gas
function jumpToAmtEaten() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    Logger.log("i = " + i);
    var r = sheets[i].getRange("B3:B")
    Logger.log("r = " + r.getA1Notation());
    var values = r.getValues();
    var day = 86400000;  
    var today = parseInt((new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)) / day);  
    var ssdate; 
    for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
      try {
        ssdate = values[j][0].getTime() / day;
      }
      catch(e) {
      }
      if (ssdate && Math.floor(ssdate) == today - 1) {
        Logger.log(Math.floor(ssdate));
        Logger.log(today);
        Logger.log(i);
        Logger.log(sheets[i]);
        Logger.log(r.offset(j, 3, 1, 1).getA1Notation());
        sheets[i].getRange(r.offset(j, 3, 1, 1).getA1Notation()).setBackground("yellow"); 
        break;                               
      }                                       
    }
  }
}
```

Also you can't use the same counter variable in nested loops as you will increment it every time you complete an interation of either one.